# AppleScript - syntax error

Tags: applescript, syntax-error

I just started using AppleScript (like 10 minutes ago really), and encountered a weird syntax error. I was just fooling around and came up with this:

```
display dialog "Press a button!" buttons{"1","2","3"}
if the button_pressed is "1" then
    display dialog "You pressed the first button!"
else if the button_pressed is "2" then
    display dialog "You pressed the second button!"
else
    display dialog "You pressed the last button!"
end if
```

It doesn't even run. It just spits out a `button_pressed is not defined` error when clearly the variable is in my program!

Comment: You spend ten minutes with Applescript, come up with one simple error, and you post here? Come on. At least put a little effort into what you're doing. -1

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable first. Try this:

```
display dialog "Press a button!" buttons {"1", "2", "3"}
set button_pressed to button returned of the result
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, "in the program" doesn't necessarily mean "defined". If a variable is defined, the words `set` and `to` are surrounding it. I don't see that anywhere in your code. This is easily resovled; just add this line before the `if` block and you'll be good to go!

```
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
```

...or even better...

```
set the button_pressed to the button returned of (display dialog "Press a button!" buttons{"1","2","3"})
```

Variables must **always** be defined before they can be used. The three exceptions are `property`s, `global` variables, and `local` variables (you'll learn about these later if you keep on with AppleScript :) ).